# How to create an Object with multiple properties of the same name

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm using the Twitter api (and twitter node module https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) to retrieve a list of numeric user ids of users belonging to a specific list. What i'd like to do is leverage this data to use in the streaming api to stream tweets from the list.

**All the code:**

```
// Call Twitter, Senti, and jQuery Node Modules
    var Twitter = require('twitter');

// Verify App with Twitter via oAuth
    var client = new Twitter({
      consumer_key: 'KEY',
      consumer_secret: 'SECRET',
      access_token_key: 'TOKEN',
      access_token_secret: 'TOKEN SECRET'
    });

// Calls list Membership data (RESTful -- Will need to be timed)

   client.get('lists/members', {slug:'LIST SLUG', owner_screen_name: 'SOMETHING', count: 500}, function(error, tweets, response){
        if (!error) {    
            console.log("Connected");
        }   

// Pulls user[].id values and pushes them to idArray

        var idArray = [];         

        for(var i in tweets.users) {
            idArray.push(tweets.users[i].id);
        }

// create object to be used as follow paramater and push idArray values to it as individual properties (All are named follow).       

        var idObj = new Object();

        for(var i in idArray) {

            var follow = "follow";
            idObj.follow = Number(idArray[i]);
        }

       console.log(idObj);


// Call Streaming api to begin stream
     client.stream('statuses/filter', idObj, function(stream) {
            stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
             console.log(tweet);
            });

            stream.on('error', function(error) {
             console.log(error);
            });
        });       
});
```

**Step1 (Works)**
I called the api, retrieve the user ids list and store them in an array.

```
  client.get('lists/members', {slug:'LIST SLUG', owner_screen_name: 'SOMETHING', count: 500}, function(error, tweets, response){
        if (!error) {    
            console.log("Connected");
        }   

// Pulls user[].id values and pushes them to idArray

        var idArray = [];         

        for(var i in tweets.users) {
            idArray.push(tweets.users[i].id);
        }
```

**The Problem**
In order to utilize the user ids as an argument when calling the streaming api them must all be contained in a single object where each property is called follow.

I'm trying to accomplish this by creating a new object and creating a single follow property in a for in loop to cycle through the array I'm storing the user ids in, but it will only return one of the array values in the object.

```
    var idObj = new Object();

    for(var i in idArray) {

        var follow = "follow";
        idObj.follow = Number(idArray[i]);
    }
```

I've done a bunch of googling but haven't been able to find a solution. If anyone has any thoughts I'd really love to hear them.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `var user_ids = { 1234: "follow", 2345: "follow", 3456: "follow" };`

Comment: "How to create an Object with multiple properties of the same name" sounds like you want: `{ follow: 1, follow: 2, follow: 3 }` which isn't allowed. Keys must be unique.

Comment: Yeah, you can't have that. Why not use an array instead: `{ follow: [1234, 12345, 123456] }`? You can then loop over that.

Comment: You can't do that. Use an array.

Comment: To be fair, if you've already got that information in `idArray` it seems like a waste of time just copying the information to a new array in an object.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on your original goal "What i'd like to do is leverage this data to use in the streaming api to stream tweets from the list" and ask instead how to achieve *that*. ..See [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)